# Variable is always true even when assigned later?

Tags: java, android

I am getting this error and I really can't understand why. The code:

```
    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            boolean b = true;
            if(b == true){
                tv1.setText("true");
                b2.setEnabled(false);
                b = false;

            } else

                if(b == false){
                b2.setEnabled(true);
                b = true;
                tv1.setText("false");
```

As you can see I'm trying to make when a button is clicked it will check if variable "b" is true or false and then it should do the following code. But it doesn't! It only does the actions for the "if b == true". Can you help me?

Comment: declare the boolean b outside of the onClick method , and it will work , the error you have done is that you put the variable b to true every time the button is clicked, so the code in the clause else will be never executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe because b is always true following this statement:

```
boolean b = true;
```

Also, b being a boolean, you can simply write:

```
if (b) {
//
} else {
//
}
```

This might work as you expect (not tested):

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    private boolean b = true;

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(b){
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            tv1.setText("true");
        } else {
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            tv1.setText("false");
        }

        b = !b; //this changes b from true to false and vice versa at each call
    }
   });
```

Comment: @Gandarez It is the problem. As for the solution, I am not sure what the OP is trying to achieve - what you propose is possibly a solution to his problem.

Comment: the original question is what happens when I click for second time in my button and my variable b still true.

Comment: The question should really be "*Why* is `b` always true when it is assigned a different value later?" ... not a very good question :)

Comment: I set b to be true but can't i change that later?

Comment: @user1250361 Yes you can. Show me the trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare the variable b outside your Listener

```
boolean b = true;
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(b == true){
                tv1.setText("true");
                b2.setEnabled(false);
                b = false;

            } else

                if(b == false){
                b2.setEnabled(true);
                b = true;
                tv1.setText("false");
```

Answer (score 1):

The variable 'b' is a local variable within the scope of the method so it is always true when the onClick() method executes. You need to move the variable into the class scope. Like this:

```
b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    boolean b = true;

    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (b) {
            tv1.setText("true");
            b2.setEnabled(false);
            b = false;

        } else {
            b2.setEnabled(true);
            b = true;
            tv1.setText("false");
        }
    }

});
```

Comment: I have edited the sample code to properly show what the code should be.

Comment: Thanks but it did not work. I have these 2 buttons and when i press one of them the other should be unpressable but then if i press it again i should again be pressable. but my button keep beeing unpressable

Comment: Just remove the boolean b = true "inside" the function. let the outside one remain. It would work then.

Comment: I have tryed putting the boolean b = true; over the onclick listener and under. and i have tryed removing the else. but non of it seems to work

Comment: I have gotten it to work by assylias answer but thanks anyway

Comment: Great! As long as you find an answer, that is what is important. :)

Answer (score 0):

you'd want to use the static modifier to keep the state of the variable ( since its state will not be kept when it goes out of scope.) this also means that you'd have to move the variable out to a global scope.

Comment: That would work in C ... but this is Java. (The scoping is an issue, but adding a `static` modifier is not even valid in this context in Java.)

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you put up, this is the reason I can think of:

Initially, your b variable is set to true. Hence, it enters the `b == true` condition.

But when you set the `b==false` "inside" that if, it DOES NOT go to else. The reason is simply because, when you have gone to the "if" statement already, that is the condition for if statement was verified to be true, the computer doesnt need to look for the "else" statement and hence doesn't go into it.

If you would have had two consecutive ifs instead of else, your thing would have worked the way you expect it to be.

Comment: okay i have now removed the "else" but it did not work :( did i understand it right?